# Django django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__users_profile.location

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, model

I have the following model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    location = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=5)

    
    



    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

I was testing some things out and put `null=True` for `location`. Then I changed it to `default=None`. After that when I tried to run `makemigrations` followed by `migrate`.

I got the following error

**Full Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uddin\project\trade\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\uddin\project\trade\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 236, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 138, in alter_field
    super().alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 571, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 360, in _alter_field
    self._remake_table(model, alter_field=(old_field, new_field))
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 283, in _remake_table
    self.execute("INSERT INTO %s (%s) SELECT %s FROM %s" % (
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__users_profile.location
```

I went through the migrations folder and changed each migration that had `null=True` to `default=None`, but I still seem to get the error? Anything I'm not seeing?

Comment: There is no `null=True` on that field. So where you migrate with this default, it will not accept a NULL.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what do you mean by this? I migrated with `null=True` and it migrated fine, but then when I removed it the issue started ocuring

Comment: @MegaBeyworld: of course, you can not remove the `null=True`, since (a) there can be records in the database with `NULL`; and (b), your `default=None` will each time conflict with the fact that the field is non-NULLable.